# React Query Page Cache On Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, react-query

I am fetching a get API in one page and handling a post API in another page. In the fetching page I have applied pagination and the page number is used in the query key. Since data is cached in react query upon creating a new post request when I navigate the fetching page on changing pages it shows the old data first then after few seconds it re-fetches and updates which is compromising the user experience.

**POST API**

```
function handleCreateOrderRequest(
      data: orderApiRequest
    ): Promise<mutateOrderApiResponse> {
      console.log(data);
      return axios.post(`/order`, data).then((res) => res.data);
    }

    const onSuccess = async () => {
      // navigate("/products/view-product");
      localStorage.removeItem("cart");
      toast.success("Order Created Successfully");
      await queryClient.removeQueries(["all-orders"]);
    };
    const onError = (error: errorType) => {
      toast.info(viewError(error.response.data.message));
    };
    return useMutation({
      mutationFn: handleCreateOrderRequest,
      onSuccess: onSuccess,
      onError: onError,
      retry: 0,
    });
  };
```

`removeQueries` removes the cache but I have another external site in which I am only fetching the API it obviously wont work there.

**GET API**

```
  const useFetchAllOrdersService = (
    page: number,
    limit: number,
    uid: string | undefined,
    statusFilter: number,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    actions: (order: orderResponseData) => actionType[]
  ) => {
    function fetchCustomerOrderRequest(): Promise<allOrdersApiResponse> {
      return axios
        .get(
          `/order/user?userId=${uid}&page=${page}&limit=${limit}${
            statusFilter != CONSIGNMENT_STATUS.ALL
              ? `&status=${statusFilter}`
              : ""
          }`
        )
        .then((res) => res.data);
    }

    return useQuery({
      queryFn: fetchCustomerOrderRequest,
      keepPreviousData: true,
      queryKey: [`all-orders`, page, statusFilter, uid],
      retry: 0,      ),
    });
  };
```

[image]